# Can you recommend me a book about integration?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, contest-math, recreational-mathematics, indefinite-integrals

I'm new to this site.
I'm an university student in korea and I major in engineering.
Recently, I've been quite interested in calculating integration. So nowadays as my hobby, I seek many interesting problems via my colleague's question, many kind of mathematical competition(putnam), or something else.
I wonder if there are any books that listed lots of facts(technics...) about integration, including many challenging problems. Especially, One of my friends recommended me a book called 'inside interesting integral'. But there is few way I can get this book. Would you mind recommending similar books, or some sites?
Thanks:)